# Calling a @RPC method outside of volttron

Tags: volttron

Say I have a running volttron agent with a @RPC decorated method (if that's relevant). Are there any ways to call that method from outside of the volttron platform? (In my case from a django web server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An agent may register endpoints on the VOLTTRON web service. A callback may be setup for the endpoint as needed.

The web service must be enabled and the agent needs to pass "enable_web=True" to the base agent constructor.

You can find the documentation and examples here: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/specifications/webframework.html

Answer (score 0):

Along with what [kyle-monson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6525452/kyle-monson) mentions, you also have to run Volttron using the bind argument. This will expose the registered endpoints on the bind arg given.
e.g `volttron -vv --bind-web-address "https://127.0.0.1:7080"

**OR** specify the bind-web-address in the ~/.volttron/config

```
[volttron]
message-bus = rmq
bind-web-address = https://127.0.0.1:7080
```

Then you can send HTTP POST request to `https://127.0.0.1:7080/rpc-method-name`

`rpc-method-name` in the request URL being the registered method using `self.vip.web.register_endpoint("/rpc-method-name", self.call_back_method_for_endpoint)`

The call back method takes in two parameters "env" and "data"

For more details on this two parameters check the docs [here](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/main/agent-framework/web-framework.html)